# У меня не правильно скачивается python?

Tags: python, установка, exe

[image: Сюда скачался python, но где python.exe?]

Сюда скачался python, но где python.exe?

Comment: Здесь подробно описано было, когда сам устанавливал
https://pythonclass.ru/python/Ustanovka-Python/

Answer (score 2):

У вас в настройках системы не включена опция отображать расширения для файлов. Зайдите в закладку "Вид" (на вашем скриншоте вверху) и включите.
По сути, python.exe это python, как сейчас отображается.