# Где должен располагаться файл python33.dll?

Tags: python, dll

Где должен располагаться файл python33.dll? Нечаянно удалил его, а теперь скачал заново. Но программы его не находят. Где он должен располагаться?

Comment: Скорее всего, в корне с программой.

Comment: python33.dll нужен для Python 3.3, не уверен что у вас такая старая версия Python. Если вы имели в виду python39.dll, посмотрите скриншот в одном из ваших вопросов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249513/%D0%A3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-python

Comment: Правда, у меня последняя версия python.Но в ошибке указан python33.dll (когда я захожу в sublime text) Думаю, проблема в sublime.